# "Expected End of Statement" when concatenating string

Tags: html, iframe, vbscript, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am attempting to embed an PDF iframe viewer into a web based form I am building.

I have done this multiple times but for the life of me I can not get it right this time.

```
''This attaches a PDF uploaded on a previous form and should display it within
''an iFrame.
If "aObjects("RD20_AttachRandR")" <> "avar1" Then
    fcLabel = "<iframe src=""" & "aObjects("RD20_AttachRandR ")" & ".PDF" & _
              " width=800px height=1000px ><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>"
End If
```

Somewhere in the line starting with `fcLabel` I am missing an `"` that ends the string that I am passing through. But I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `aObjects` is a dictionary (or other collection) variable, so you need to remove the outer double quotes. Also, the second time you use that variable the item name string has a trailing space (`"RD20_AttachRandR "`) which you may want to remove.

```
If aObjects("RD20_AttachRandR") <> "avar1" Then
    fcLabel = "<iframe src=""" & aObjects("RD20_AttachRandR") & ".PDF" & _
              " width=800px height=1000px ><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar,

The aObjects is an object in the form containing the string to where the file is. I have tried removing the outer double quotes and it changes my error to:

              Error: Type mismatch: 'aObjects'

I am trying to see if I might be able to build a work around for now.

Comment: Check the actual type of the variable and the item you're trying to access: `MsgBox TypeName(aObjects) : MsgBox TypeName(aObjects("RD20_AttachRandR"))`. Note that you had a trailing space in the string (`"RD20_AttachRandR "`).

Comment: Hi Ansgar,

Thank you very much, it was the trailing space at the end of the aObject name and that seemed to be the cause of the problem.

I replaced the double quotations as it was still required.

Thank you for your assistance.

Kind Regards,
F

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Ansgar Wiechers,

I had forgotten to remove a trailing space at the end of the aObject name.

I removed it and it works now.

Ta.